# Modal no abre, se queda en negro

Tags: php, bootstrap

He realizado una dataTable con una crud, al momento de darle en el boton editar se abre el modal y me deja editar correctamente, pero cuando voy a eliminar el registro no se abre el modal y me sale la pantalla negra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá aparece la pantalla negra al darle en borrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo de la dataTable con los botones del modal, editar y borrar**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
                        <thead class="text-center text-uppercase">
                            <tr>
                                <th>codigo</th>
                                <th>Tipo personal</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($listaTipo as $tipo) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <?php echo $tipo["codTipoPersonal"]; ?> </td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $tipo["nombreTipo"]; ?> </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalEditarT<?php echo $tipo["codTipoPersonal"]; ?>">Editar</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalBorrarT<?php echo $tipo["codTipoPersonal"]; ?>">Borrar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                
                                <?php include("./modalTipo/modalEditar.php"); ?>
 
                                <?php include("./modalTipo/modalBorrar.php"); ?>

                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Codigo del modal borrar**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modalBorrarT<?php echo $tipo['codTipoPersonal']; ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
                <h5 class="modal-title">¿Realmente deseas eliminar este cargo?</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <?php echo "CARGO ". $tipo["nombreTipo"]; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="../bd/crudTipo.php?id=<?php echo $tipo["codTipoPersonal"]; ?>" method="POST">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="borrar" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

He intentado sacar el include del modal borrar de la etiqueta table, pero no funciona solo me muestra un registro, espero me puedan ayudar gracias!

Comment: Deberías tener solo una ventana modal para editar y otra para eliminar, además, deben estar fuera de la tabla, porque "rompen" la estructura HTML, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/376954/54039) para ver lo que pasa y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/420846/54039) para ver cómo usar solo una modal.

Comment: Sí, tengo las ventanas de los modal separadas, es decir una para editar y otra para eliminar como comente anteriormente la ventana de editar me funciona perfectamente, pero la de eliminar no!

Comment: Por favor revisa los enlaces sugeridos.